# Validate required field

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

All.
I use play framework and I have a problem with the validate required fields.
Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "office")
public class Office extends AppModel{
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required(message = "asdfasfd")
    public String name;
...
}
```

Controller:

```
public static Result update() {
    Form<Office> filledForm = form(Office.class).bindFromRequest();
    if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {
        String errorMsg = getErrors(filledForm.errors());
        flash("error", errorMsg);
        return badRequest(edit.render("Edit", filledForm));

    }
    Office office = filledForm.get();
...
}
```

View:

```
@(title: String, officeFrom: Form[Office])
...
<h1>@officeFrom.get.getName</h1>
...
```

If on form removed from the field value `name` I get an error when saving

```
[IllegalStateException: Error(s) binding form: {"name":["Field required"]}]
```

how to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's because you call `@officeFrom.get.` in the template

You specify that `name` is required, so when you call `officeFrom.get` it verify constraints and generate an error if values violate constraints. In your case, "name" is empty.

You need to use `@fficeFrom("name").value` - this will not check constarints.